# Eclipse not launching? How do I save my projects?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been using eclipse to learn how to program Java and one day when I tried to use Eclipse it would not open.  I get the purple window with a loading bar but when that gets about half way it crashes but does not give me any report as to why it crashed. How could I fix Eclipse or how could I save my projects so that I can reinstall Eclipse?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Answer (score 1):

Your projects are already saved in your hard disk. You just need to reinstall, and when you open again to give the specific path to your projects.

Comment: Tanks! Eclipse works now  but I cannot access any if my old projects. They are all in the workspace like before.

Answer (score 0):

Your projects (Eclipse workspace folder) are saved on your hard-drive . It has nothing to do with your Eclipse crash. If the folder is located inside Eclipse folder, just copy it to some other location. If it is already outside, you are safe.

If you re-install Eclipse, just use this copied workspace as your Eclipse workspace, it should just work fine.

Note: It would be easy to fix existing Eclipse, given you provide exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

be cool , you can get your projects without any problem 
1) go to eclipse.org ("https://eclipse.org/downloads/") and download eclipse and re-install then it will bind with your  existing workspace in eclipse then you can open your projects through eclipse

2)eclipse default  workspace  is" C:\Users\yourname\workspace "  manualy go to this link in here replace "yourname" with your PC name and get your projects